# Liquibase doesn't load *.sql from classpath inside of changeSet

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-data-jpa, liquibase

I need configure changeSet executing sql loaded from jar.

I have internal project `changeSet` that works correctly

```
<changeSet id="1" author="sergii" dbms="h2">
  <sqlFile
    encoding="utf8"
    path="schema-ms-sql.0.0.1.sql"
    relativeToChangelogFile="true"
    splitStatements="true"
    stripComments="true"/>
</changeSet>
```

Some scripts are provided from different libraries (in my case it is `spring-boot-starter-batch`), for example:

```
classpath:/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-h2.sql
```

Note that jar is in the project and accessible (build \ test\ run times).
As result I need register one also into my `changeSet`, trying:

```
<changeSet id="2" author="sergii" dbms="h2">
  <sqlFile
    encoding="utf8"
    path="classpath*:/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-h2.sql"
    relativeToChangelogFile="true"
    splitStatements="true"
    stripComments="true"/>
</changeSet>
```

and it doesn't work with any configuration (like `"classpath:/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-h2.sql"`, `"/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-h2.sql"`, `"org/springframework/batch/core/schema-h2.sql"`, `"classpath*:/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-h2.sql"` and so on) because of

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: java.io.IOException: File does not exist: 'classpath*:/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-h2.sql'
```

I know using spring I could use auto configuration, but I'm interested in liquibase auditing...

Is any ideas how to make packaged scripts working via `changeSet` or include into liquibase auditing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution is to change attribute for `sqlFile` tag:

```
relativeToChangelogFile="false"
```

Result `changeSet` below:

```
<changeSet id="2" author="sergii" dbms="h2">
  <sqlFile
    encoding="utf8"
    path="classpath:/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-h2.sql"
    relativeToChangelogFile="false"
    splitStatements="true"
    stripComments="true"/>
</changeSet>
```

Comment: notice that with the liquibase-maven-plugin version 3.8.6 this does not work, I had to update plugin to the latest version (at the moment 4.0.0)

Answer (score 1):

Example for separate changelog.yaml file with relative path:

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
      id: my_script_1
      changes:
          - sqlFile:
                dbms: mysql
                encoding: utf8
                path: db/changelog/0_0_1/my_script_1.sql    
                relativeToChangelogFile: false
                splitStatements: true
                stripComments: true
      rollback:
          - sqlFile:
                dbms: mysql
                encoding: utf8
                path: db/changelog/0_0_1/my_script_1_rollback.sql
                relativeToChangelogFile: false
                splitStatements: true
                stripComments: true
  - changeSet:
      id: my_script_2
      changes:
        - sqlFile:
            dbms: mysql
            encoding: utf8
            path: db/changelog/0_0_1/my_script_2.sql
            relativeToChangelogFile: false
            splitStatements: true
            stripComments: true
      rollback:
        - sqlFile:
            dbms: mysql
            encoding: utf8
            path: db/changelog/0_0_1/my_script_2_rollback.sql
            relativeToChangelogFile: false
            splitStatements: true
            stripComments: true
```